# How do you switch all the other booleans to false when you click a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      show: false,
      show2: false,
      cards: [{ name: "card 1" }, { name: "card 1" }, { name: "card 1" }],
    };
  },

};
</script>
```

```html
 <v-list-item @click="drawer = !drawer">
            <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item @click="show = !show">
            show1
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item @click="show2 = !show2">
            show2
</v-list-item>



<div v-if="show == true">
          <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col v-for="card in cards" :key="card">
              <v-card
                dark
                tile
                height="200"
                width="98%"
                style="display: inline-flex"
                class="ma-2"
              >
                <v-card-title>
                  {{ card.name }}
                </v-card-title>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </div>
   
        <div v-if="show2 == true">
          <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col>
              <v-card
                dark
                tile
               
                width="98%"
                style="display: inline-flex"
                class="ma-2"
              >
             </v-col>
             </v-row>
             </div>
```

How would I change show2 to false if I click show1? And would it work with multiple booleans? I have tried mapping through the array but i cant seem to figure out how to do it.

Also would it be better to use this method to transition between sections or should I use :router-to and use a transition that way?

Comment: <v-list-item @click="show = !show; show2 = false;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any problem with using this method for transition between sections. It is up to your preference. You can write a method in order to manipulate two different data at the same time. It should look like this:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      show: false,
      show2: false,
      cards: [{ name: "card 1" }, { name: "card 1" }, { name: "card 1" }],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickShowOne() {
            this.show2 = false;
            this.show = !this.show;
        },
        clickShowTwo() {
            this.show2 = !this.show2;
        }
  }

};
</script>
```

And use it like this:

```html
 <v-list-item @click="drawer = !drawer">
            <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item @click="clickShowOne">
            show1
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item @click="clickShowTwo">
            show2
</v-list-item>
```